# Turn off Vim highlightinh in .yaml files

Tags: vim

[image]

In my Vim, it hightlights some text like shown in the above picture. I have tried many ways of turning it off, e.g syntax off ..etc.. but it didn't work.

Comment: Try with `:set t_Co=0` and `:set nohlsearch`.

Comment: it remains the same, no change

Comment: Try open the file with `vim -u NONE` and repeat setttings above to locate the problem.

Comment: When I open the file with vim -u NONE docker-compose-ha.yml ..it works..no hightlights.. I assume that launch of vim is without .vimrc . How would I find which is the root cause

Comment: Try now with `vim -u NORC` if ok then the problem is from `.vimrc` file. If not try with `vim --noplugin` if ok then the problem is from plugins to make sure.